# 2006 Hyundai Sonata GLS emissions fail

Tags: hyundai, o2-sensor, emissions, sonata

I own a 2006 Hyundai Sonata GLS 3.3L v6 and recently gave it for some repair work after which the car failed emissions test.The shop told me that the oxygen sensor and Catalyst Monitor are not ready and I have to drive it for some time. 
I am also using Turbo app with Bafx OBDII Bluetooth adapter to continuously check while driving if the sensor reads complete/ready state but its not completing.
Do I have to replace the sensors? ?Is there any specific drive cycle for this car as I am not able to find one on the internet.

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

There are specific steps involved with the drive cycle. I pulled this from [this site.](http://www.smogtips.com/smog-question/2932/Hyundai-Sonata-Monitors-Not-Ready) You are not completing *some part of it*.

> Hyundai Sonata Drive Cycle
>
> **STEP 1:**
>
> - Make sure check engine light is not on and that there are no stored trouble codes in the computer. Use a scan tool to check for OBD II trouble codes. Any faults founds need to be repaired first.
> - Start the engine. Keep the vehicle in Park.
> - Idle the engine for 1 1/2 minutes.
>
> **STEP 2: (Steady State Driving - Part 1)**
>
> - Accelerate within 15 seconds to 50-55 mph (using 1/4 to 3/4 throttle) and keep this speed steady for 2 to 3 minutes.
> - Decelerate to 0 mph without braking.
> - Idle engine then idle in Drive for 1 to 2 minutes.
>
> **STEP 3: (Steady State Driving - Part 2)**
>
> - Accelerate within 15 seconds to 50-55 mph (using 1/4 to 3/4 throttle) and keep this speed steady for 10 to 20 minutes.
> - Decelerate to 0 mph without braking.
> - Idle engine then idle in Drive for 1 to 2 minutes.
>
> **STEP 4: (Engine Stop)**
>
> - The drive cycle is completed.
> - Turn off the engine (key in the OFF position).

Also remember, do not erase or reset anything with your OBDII scanner during any of this, as it will cause you to need to completely redo the drive cycle. You won't know for if you'll need to replace any sensors until it gets past the drive cycle. At that point you'll see if it passes or fails.

Answer (score 0):

Gas level must be between 1/2 and 1/4 of a tank for one of the EVAP tests to run, else EVAP monitor will stay at incomplete regardless of the how/when/external temps/etc. that you drive.
I have not ever let the car go from 55 to 0 on its own (without braking), for EVAP tests to complete, and they have completed without doing this.